# LXQt broken desktop after reboot - don't know how to fix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop, ubuntu-20.04, lubuntu

I hope to find here some help, because I can't find a solution and tried nearly everything what I know.

After a reboot the Desktop has disappeared and pcmanfm-qt is not starting. (Can't reproduce it, because I don't changed anything to the system) Here first my system configuration which worked for nearly a year without problems:

1. Environment: LXQt
2. Displaymanager: xdm
3. Window Manager: openBox
4. System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

What I tried:

1. reinstall LXQt `sudo apt install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop`
2. Also tried: `sudo apt purge lxqt openbox -y` && `sudo apt-get install lxqt openbox -y` && `sudo tasksel install lubuntu-desktop`
3. change display manager `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xdm`, (&& Window Manager, also without success), tried sddm && mutter
4. tried to reinstall `pcman sudo apt-get install --reinstall pcmanfm-qt`
5. also tried: `lxpanelctl restart && openbox --restart`

Nothing brought the desktop back. My Desktop looks at the moment only black, without folders, .desktop files and no wallpaper. In my despair I tried to reinstall the graphical environment:

```
sudo su
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f instal
apt-getupdate
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Also without success :(

If someone could take me by the hand and help me it would be absolutly great! Because all my system is great configured for my studies and I really don't want to loose this configuration with a reinstall or something. Unfortunately, despite the greatest effort, I cannot find a solution on my own.

I can also post outputs or config files, if necessary.

Other maybe important note: I'm using X11, because with wayland I had problems 1 year ago after clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself with a quick & dirty solution. If someone faces same or simmilar problem in the future:

Solved with a rename of the /home/username/./config:

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config_bak
```

After that just copy pasted the configs from .config_bak to .config again (override).
Think it was something wrong with pcman-qt.

If someone have after that problems with xterm, just go to `/usr/bin/` copy qterminal and paste on same place and rename to xterm.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I found was from https://www.publish0x.com/a-bit-of-everything/restore-default-panel-in-lubuntu-2004-xmdjogv :

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/lxqt/panel.conf ~/.config/lxqt/
$ reboot
```

This solution only modifies the relevant config file, and avoids re-creating the user (as suggested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/707228/how-to-reset-debian-11-lxqt-desktop-configuration)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).